# Android- How to send string array as email body

Tags: android, email

I need to send some data as email on button click.I successfully added data from edit text.But I donot know how to send an array of data from my database.In my code I need to send values of pn[i].I added the value like this.but it caused error in this line

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"name:"+edt1.getText().toString()+"\n"+"products:"+pn[i]);
```

Code:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mydb=buy_ltr.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add2cart WHERE usr='"+cont+"'", null);
            String [] pn = new String[cr.getCount()];

            int i = 0;
            while(cr.moveToNext())
            {

                String prp = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("prate"));
                pn[i] = prp;
                i++;
            }


              Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              String[] recipients = new String[]{"my@email.com", "",};
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test");
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is email's message");
              emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"name:"+edt1.getText().toString()+"\n"+"address:"+edt2.getText().toString()+"\n"+"products:"+pn[i]);
              emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
              startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
              finish();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to send all entries of the array or just a specific entry?

Comment: I want to send all entries of the array.

Comment: Ok, so you will have to merge all array items into one string. Do you want a delimiter between the items? Maybe a space character or a comma?

Comment: yes,On sending as email.I need something to separate each items in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method one:** (Build in method)

```
String productNames = Arrays.toString(pn);
```

**Method two:** (Each product on a new line)

```
StringBuilder productNamesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(String productName: pn){
    productNamesBuilder.append(productName + "\n");
}
String productNames = productNamesBuilder.toString();
```

**Method three:** (Numbered list, each product on a new line)

```
StringBuilder productNamesBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < pn.length; i++){
    productNamesBuilder.append((i + 1) + " " + pn[i] + "\n");
}
String productNames = productNamesBuilder.toString();
```